# Difference in Nuance: 嬉しい vs. 喜ぶ , 幸せ vs. 幸い vs. 幸福

Tags: words, nuances

These are all words that have to do with happiness. Aside from their word classes, what difference do they have in nuance?

Answer (score 5):

One difference is that 嬉しい is more an immediate feeling, a kind of spontaneous emotion that emerges in certain situations, whereas 幸せ is a deeper kind of happiness which is based on more stable circumstances. When your girlfriend gives you a great present, you feel 嬉しい in that moment. When she stays with you and you develop a deep and fulfilling relationship together, you could feel 幸せ.

My sense is that 幸福 is similar to 幸せ in terms of its meaning, but it is more formal as a word (as many 漢語 are), so you would be more likely to encounter it in written Japanese.

幸い has more of a 'lucky' or 'fortunate' meaning, usually used to refer to a specific event which was deemed to be somehow fortuitous.

Comment: I forgot about　喜ぶ. In my opinion one of the best translations for 喜ぶ is 'to be glad'. It's not as happy as 嬉しい but it is still a spontaneous emotion which you feel in the moment, rather than a long term thing.

Comment: FWIW, one possible gloss for 幸せ that fits the "stable" sense might be _"contentment"_.

Comment: 幸福 is also the translation for *eudaimonia*.

Comment: I would think the nuances are similar to how you describe happiness and joy, in whether which one is temporary or lasting.

Comment: @ keithmaxx I don't agree with you here. You could use 'happy' to describe either a momentary emotion or a long term feeling. It has both senses, whereas you couldn't use 嬉しい to talk about deeper lasting happiness.

Comment: @virmaior, it totally makes sense that 幸福 transtlates as _eudaimonia_ too, since it includes the kanji 福 which carries the nuance of _blessing_. Thanks for pointing it out.